# Question regarding canonical covering of a locally compact metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Show that any open covering of a locally compact metrizable space $X$ can be refined to a canonical covering .
We say that a closed set $F$ of a topological space $X$ is called canonical if $F=\overline{\operatorname{Int}(F)}$ . A locally finite covering $\alpha=\{F_{\lambda}\}$ of a locally compact space $X$ is called a canonical covering if each $F_{\lambda}$ is a canonical closed set and $Int(F_{\lambda})\cap Int(F_{\delta})=\emptyset$ for all $\lambda\neq \delta.$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ The details of canonical coverings as well as the solution of my problem is given in a paper "Homology Theory and the Exactness Axiom" by EG Skylarenko . I am attaching a screenshot as well as the link to the paper . At first , he takes a locally finite refinement
$\{U_{\lambda}\}$ of the open cover and that's possible because $X$ is metrizable . Then he  orders the elements arbitrarily as $U_1,U_2,\cdots,U_{\lambda},\cdots$ but I can't find why that set can be ordered in such a way and after that he somewhat proceeds inductively . Does that mean the refinement has countably many elements ? The paper is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HAeHO8uXJMDF7NZL7URGrR4RHszzNmx2/view?usp=drivesdk) with page number $112.$

I am getting confused by this statement and need some leads . Thanks in advance for any help .[image]

Comment: He may be using well-ordering and transfinite recursion, since there doesn't seem to be any separability assumption.  Regardless, the argument still seems to work.  Basically the axiom of choice is equivalent to the well-ordering theorem (every set can be well-ordered), and on a well-ordered  set recursion and induction work, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction

Comment: Let me add that while the Wikipedia article I linked refers to ordinals, knowledge of ordinals isn't really necessary for transfinite induction/recursion, the concepts work as well for any well-ordered set.

Comment: Are you sure that canonical subsets are closed? From your definition, they are open. Also, what is $\varphi$? Do you mean $\emptyset$?

Comment: @MoisheKohan looks like it is mis-stated in the question, in the excerpt it is defined as $F=\overline{{\operatorname{Int}(F)}}$.

Comment: @MW: OK, that would make sense. The issue then is what else is misstated in the OP.

Comment: I do think it looks from the excerpt like the author almost certainly had transfinite induction in mind and could have been more explicit about it, though there is always the possibility some separability assumption is buried deep in the paper elsewhere - I didn't see it on a quick glance through.

Comment: @MW, thanks . And yes, the separability condition maybe is lurking somewhere in the proof (or in other related proofs) but I can't see clearly .

Comment: @MoisheKohan, sorry . I've edited it now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skylarenko deals with an **arbitrary** locally compact metrizable space $X$; he definitely does not make a separability assumption.

For example, each uncountable discrete space is locally compact metrizable, and the open cover consisting of all singletons does not have a countable refinement.

Therefore it is clear that he must use **transfinite induction**.

> order the elements $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_λ, \ldots$ arbitrarily.

What he needs is a *well-ordering* of the open covering $\alpha$. Then in particular $\alpha$ has a smallest element $U_1$, $\alpha \setminus \{U_1\}$ has a smallest element $U_2$ etc.

Let $R_\lambda : I(\lambda) \to \mathfrak C(X)$ be a function from the initial segment $I(\lambda) = \{ \mu \in \alpha \mid \mu < \lambda\}$ of $\alpha$ to the set $\mathfrak C(X)$ of canonical sets in $X$ such that the $F_\mu = R_\lambda(U_\mu)$ satisfy the appropriate conditions needed for a canonical covering. Skylarenko then extends $R_\lambda$ to $I(\lambda) \cup \{\lambda\}$ by
$$F_\lambda = [U_\lambda \setminus \bigcup_{\mu < \lambda} F_\mu]$$
Observe that this already covers the case $\lambda = 1$ since $\bigcup_{\mu < \lambda} F_\mu = \emptyset$.

The principle of transfinite construction gives then a function
$$R : \alpha \to  \mathfrak C(X)$$ which is nothing else than the desired canoical covering.